Imgur uploads via API in Python, previously working, suddenly failing with SSL error "EOF occurred in violation of protocol"
I have an application using the ImgurPython library to help me upload albums in bulk with fewer headaches than the web UI causes. It's been working well for me for a few weeks, but recently stopped. Uploads fail, but other API calls seem fine. Nothing changed on my end (that I'm aware of), and various things I've tried haven't identified a cause, so I'm at a loss.
I've been able to repro the failure in the Python command line:
>>> import os, sys, re, time
>>> from imgurpython import ImgurClient
>>> sys.version
'3.12.0 (tags/v3.12.0:0fb18b0, Oct  2 2023, 13:03:39) [MSC v.1935 64 bit (AMD64)]'
>>> client_id = "..."
>>> client_secret = "..."
>>> access_token = "..."
>>> refresh_token = "..."
>>> client = ImgurClient(client_id, client_secret, access_token, refresh_token)
>>> client.get_credits()
{'UserLimit': 500, 'UserRemaining': 500, 'UserReset': 1712002684, 'ClientLimit': 12500, 'ClientRemaining': 12499}
>>> fpath = '...'
>>> fd = open(fpath, 'rb')
>>> res = client.upload(fd, anon=False)
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2406)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 847, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 515, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.imgur.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /3/upload (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2406)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\imgurpython-1.1.7-py3.12.egg\imgurpython\client.py", line 598, in upload
  File "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\imgurpython-1.1.7-py3.12.egg\imgurpython\client.py", line 133, in make_request
  File "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 115, in post
    return request("post", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 517, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.imgur.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /3/upload (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2406)')))

What doesn't seem to be the issue: I don't seem to be over my usage limits. I can connect and check credits and see everything says I have my full allotment or very close to it. I can make GET calls (e.g. checking the contents of an album) and POST calls (e.g. creating an album). It only seems to be uploads specifically that cause the problem.
It doesn't seem to affect one specific image file, and the files I'm trying to upload aren't notably different from ones that have worked fine in the past (the above repro uses a file that it already did work with).
I can switch to different VPN endpoints or turn off my VPN and it doesn't make a difference. I've waited more than a day before retrying and I still hit the failure. I waited for the new month to start today in case that was a factor, but still hit the failure. (The API docs say "If the daily limit is hit five times in a month, then the app will be blocked for the rest of the month", so I was hoping that might be the cause and that it might mean the rest of the calendar month rather than the next thirty days - but either I'm unlucky there, or the fact that only uploads are failing means the app isn't blocked after all.) I tried getting a different app ID/secret and using that - same problem.
I've found various questions here and elsewhere about similar-looking failures but none that seem to be quite the same. One answer recommended using sessions in the requests library calls, but ImgurPython seems to already be doing that.

I had a similar experience. I stopped using that library and just used requests to speak directly to the API instead. Here's an example to upload an image. Reference the docs here too https://apidocs.imgur.com/#c85c9dfc-7487-4de2-9ecd-66f727cf3139.
import requests
from os import path

clientID = '..'
headers = {'Authorization': 'Client-ID ' + clientID}
url = 'https://api.imgur.com/3/upload'
with open(path.realpath('./original.png'), 'rb') as img:
    payload = {'image': img}
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=payload)
    imageLink = response.json()['data']['link']
    return imageLink


Interesting... this worked, but it uploads the image anonymously, which I don't prefer. I tried authorizing as the user rather than client and passing in a bearer token instead of the client ID, but that just got me the same error again. So, perhaps the issue really is with usage limits, and the information coming back from the API telling me how much usage I have left is misleading or incomplete...
Did you hit this issue around the same time (suggesting it's a change on Imgur's side) or some other time entirely?

I forgot to get back to you. I was doing something similar ( trying to upload thousands of photos ) and I kept running into that very same error every ~50 uploads. I'm pretty sure it is another usage limit they have. I just ended up using a different image hosting service.

The fifty-upload limit is documented and I've tried to set up my client to avoid exceeding it. I suspect what may have happened is that I accidentally overran too many times and have triggered a limit which isn't reflected in the rate-limit headers returned with my requests. If that's so I'll need to wait a full month to retry, which is a real pain, made more so by the lack of accessible information. Still, thanks for the workaround.
